# JHipster/LDAP - Create new user in JHipster BDD on first connection

Tags: spring, ldap

i'm new on JHipster and configured LDAP from the official source ([JHipster LDAP](https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/016_tip_ldap_authentication.html)).

LDAP authentication is ok now and works well.

Now i want to create new user on first connection in JHipster database.

The user informations for name/mail/... are on LDAP.

The creation must happen after successful authent from LDAP.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the answer.

After Jhipster LDAP connection implementation, you need to modify the class CustomAuthenticationManager:authenticate by replacing the mapUserFromContext method with the following code :

```
@Override
        public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> clctn) {
            Optional<User> isUser = userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(username);
            if(!isUser.isPresent()){
                UserDTO newUser = new UserDTO();
                newUser.setLogin(authentication.getName());
                newUser.setFirstName(ctx.getStringAttribute("givenName"));
                newUser.setLastName(ctx.getStringAttribute("sn"));
                newUser.setEmail(ctx.getStringAttribute("mail"));
                newUser.setLangKey("fr");
                newUser.setImageUrl("youimageurl");
                userService.registerUser(newUser, "1");
            }
            isUser = userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(username);
            final User user = isUser.get();
            Set<Authority> userAuthorities = user.getAuthorities();
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Authority a: userAuthorities){
                GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
                    a.getName());
                grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);
            }
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                username, "" , grantedAuthorities);
        }
```

A new user (newUser) is created if the login user is not known in JHipster database (Happen after success of the LDAP authentication).

Use ctx.getStringAttribute("ldapProperty") to get informations from the LDAP.